# I want the null condition be zero in the table

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from  
(select 
b.state,b.Region,b.Area,b.Sector,b.Zone,a.Mobile,a.Mason_code,a.Mason_Name,
a.M_address,
c.CustomerRef,c.NoOfBags,c.offtakedate,
datepart(day,offtakedate) as [day]
from Rmcl_Mason_dtl as a,MACE_Rep_Area_Master as b,
RMCL_MACEAPP_Offtake_Dtl as c
where 
a.State=b.State_Code
and a.Region=b.Region_Code
and a.Zone=b.Zone_Code
and a.Area=b.Area_Code
and a.Sector=b.Sector_Code
and c.MasonNo=a.Mobile
and MONTH([OfftakeDate]) = 10 AND YEAR([OfftakeDate]) = 2017
and NoOfBags IS not null
group by 
b.state,b.Region,b.Area,b.Sector,b.Zone,a.Mobile,a.Mason_code,
a.Mason_Name,a.M_address,c.customerRef,c.NoOfBags,c.offtakeDate
```

I want to change the null values into zeros
then what I want to use the condition for execution

Comment: did you find anything useful? than please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use coalesce which will return the first non-null value.

```
Coalesce(Your_Column, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ISNULL Function

```
ISNULL(Your_Column, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you would need ISNULL:

```
select * from  
(select 
    ISNULL(b.state, 0) state, 
    ISNULL(b.Region, 0) Region, 
    ISNULL(b.Area, 0) Area, 
    ISNULL(b.Sector, 0) Sector, 
    ISNULL(b.Zone, 0) Zone, 
    ISNULL(a.Mobile, 0) Mobile, 
    ISNULL(a.Mason_code, 0) Mason_code,
    ISNULL(a.Mason_Name, 0) Mason_Name,
    ISNULL(a.M_address, 0) M_address,
    ISNULL(c.CustomerRef, 0) CustomerRef,
    ISNULL(c.NoOfBags, 0) NoOfBags,
    ISNULL(c.offtakedate, 0) offtakedate,
    ISNULL(datepart(day,offtakedate), 0) as [day]
from Rmcl_Mason_dtl as a,MACE_Rep_Area_Master as b,
    RMCL_MACEAPP_Offtake_Dtl as c
where 
    a.State=b.State_Code
    and a.Region=b.Region_Code
    and a.Zone=b.Zone_Code
    and a.Area=b.Area_Code
    and a.Sector=b.Sector_Code
    and c.MasonNo=a.Mobile
    and MONTH([OfftakeDate]) = 10 AND YEAR([OfftakeDate]) = 2017
    and NoOfBags IS not null
group by 
    b.state,b.Region,b.Area,b.Sector,b.Zone,a.Mobile,a.Mason_code,
    a.Mason_Name,a.M_address,c.customerRef,c.NoOfBags,c.offtakeDate
```